# Values missing on dynamic properties after JSON serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm unable to globally configure my ASP.NET MVC 4 application (using Web API controllers) so that actions that return HttpResponseMessage with a Json string that includes values of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` on dynamic properties.

I can produce required output by serializing the JSON string manually in each action, but ideally I'd like to be able to globally configure the correct behaviour on Application_Start.

To demonstrate my problem, consider the following class:

```
public class Content : IAccountEntity
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public dynamic DynamicProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Given the following global serialization configuration:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...

    ConfigureJsonFormat();
}

private static void ConfigureJsonFormat()
{    
    var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

    formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

    json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
    json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

And the following MVC Action code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    ... // Other initialisation code

    content.StringProperty = "Hello world";
    content.DynamicProperty.Email = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue("test@test.com");

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
}
```

I get the following Json response. **As you can see, it is missing the value for the dynamic sub property 'email'.**

```
[
  {
    "stringProperty": "Hello world",
    "dynamicProperty": {
        email:[]
    }
  }
]
```

I can resolve the problem on a per action basis by taking a more manual approach to creating the JSON string response as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    ... // Other initialisation code

    content.StringProperty = "Hello world";
    content.DynamicProperty.Email = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue("test@test.com");

    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };

    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                    Content = new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
               };
}
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
[
  {
    "stringProperty": "Hello world",
    "dynamicProperty": {
        email: "test@test.com"
    }
  }
]
```

I would prefer however to be able to replicate the above behaviour using the global configuration.

Is there a way I can modify my method ConfigureJsonFormat so that the values for dynamics are included on the Json response without having to code for this on an action by action basis?

I'm hoping that I can set something on `json.SerializerSettings`, but have not been able to find the correct setting as yet.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. Could you show the initialization code of the `DynamicProperty`? Also it's pretty strange that the Email property is serialized as an empty array. I suspect there's something else going on here.

Comment: Looking further into this, I've found that I originally made an incorrect assumption regarding the type of DynamicProperty.Email. I had thought it was a string but it is in fact Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue (which is IEnumerable). The real code creates this value on deserialization from the data store (MongoDb), but I have tested with manual assignment using "content.DynamicContent.email = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue("test@test.com" )". The issue remains in that the serialization behaviour is different depending on whether I serialize manually or rely on the global configuration.

Comment: Why must you set the Email property to be a `JValue`? Can't you do `content.DynamicProperty.Email = "test@test.com"` ?